# Using lodash to pick defined values from an object

Tags: javascript, lodash

I'd like to pick defined values from an object according to an array of keys I supply.

Say I have an object like so:

```
{
  _id: '1234'
  status: 'complete',
  current_task: null,
  current_task_attempts: 2
}
```

I'd like to pick out the `_id`, `status` and `current_task` properties, but only if they are not `null` or `undefined`:

```
{
  _id: '1234'
  status: 'complete'
}
```

My current solution is:

```
_.pickBy(_.pick(obj, ['_id', 'status', 'current_task']))
```

But this feels a bit weird. Is there a single lodash function that can do what I want?

Comment: That looks to be as succinct as it gets. Are you strictly looking to use only one lodash function?

Answer (score 1):

It's not a single function. However, you can try using a sequence, which does exactly the same thing you did, but is a bit more readable:

```
_(obj).pick(['_id', 'status', 'current_task']).pickBy().value();
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not exactly your question, but probably a very common scenario.

```
var o = { a: 'Not empty', b: null, c: undefined, d: '', e: 100, f: {}, g: [] };

_.pickBy(o, _.isDefined);
// { a: "Not empty", e: 100, f: {…}, g: Array(0) }
```

Comment: _.isDefined is not defined

Comment: Right @mleko sorry. Still works though, but in fact it'd look like this:
`_.pickBy(o);` Leaving the predicate undefined would clear some things up in the object, but best double check that you're handling empty strings/null/undefined as you intend.